Is it OK to make an "offshape" bid if you can handle any likely response?
With no one vulnerable at atchpoints, left hand opponent opened with one heart. Partner passed, right hand opponent raised to two hearts (both of them had minimums for their bids).
I passed, holding ♠87 ♥AKJ2 ♦ AKQ9 ♣QJ3, because I was "stuck" for a bid.
I considered doubling for takeout, but feared that I could not handle the likely two spade "forced" bid from my partner. With the benefit of hindsight, it might have been OK, since partner would bid his "cheapest" four card or logner suit (he could not have more than one heart given my holding and the opponents' bidding).
Partner actually had JT96 of spades, and would have bid them, in which case I would bid 2NT, probably going down one. This contrasts with the usual offshape takeout double when you have a big hand and a five card suit to run to.
The other bid worth considering was the unusual 2NT, which seemed promising, given that partner's distribution was 4-1-4-4. I didn't have the normal 5-4 or better distribution but perhaps my extra points would have compensated.
We got a bottom for selling out so cheaply. Was either double/2 NT or 2NT (unusual) a better option, even offshape, than pass?

Agreeing with ruds.  A different POV on how to think to get to that conclusion.
Assuming the opponents "have their bids" (i.e. they're not under 50 or play Precision, where the opener could be 10 and raiser on 2-with-a-stiff), you can see what's going on.  11 or 12 on your left, 6ish on your right (do they play constructive raises, so it's 8ish on your right?), 21 in your hand - partner has nothing.  If you're really lucky, he has the ♦J or the ♥Q (stiff, of course), or the ♣Q with the A in opener, so you can get to the board once.  If you're not "really lucky", you're playing this out of your own hand, with many of the cards over you, and you might make 6 tricks.
Of course, with that heart suit, you might make the same 6 tricks defending 2♥, even "endplayed at trick 2".  Here, the spades are actually useful - as exit cards!  Plus you have the hope that partner being on lead once can make a useful lead through strength (of course, she could lead a spade and take away one of my exits.  Oh well).
Now, if they are the ultra-moderns, and partner does have 7 or so of the finest and a stiff or void heart, she might decide that "they don't play two of a fit at matchpoints" and double.  And you'll know what to do then! (I know, can we get it for -500 into the -430s of the people that doubled-and-bid-NT?  Isn't matchpoints fun?)

Pass is the correct bid. If you got a bottom, it is because opponents were unusually aggressive at your table, or because you misdefended.
Your hand screams defense. You are balanced. You have excellent values in their trump suit and a small doubleton in the unbid major. When you picked up your hand and before anyone had a chance to bid, you would have had reasonable expectations of playing in 4H your way.
In normal circumstances I would expect to get +50 defending 2H and -50 (at least) in 2NT or 3C.

Maybe we misdefended. Partner led the ace of clubs (his one other face card), which declarer ruffed, and that set up dummy's king, allowing them to make two hearts. Given that ace (which I had not counted on), we would have made 2NT instead of going down one. The opponents are very aggressive, and this time they got away with it.

(a) How did dummy have the club King when you had it as well? (b) There's a reason that we don't lead unsupported aces against a suit contract.

My club holding was QJ3, dummy had the king. My mistake. Sorry.

@TomAu You were unlucky. But there isn't really anything you could have done about it in the auction, you can't assume the opponents are always overbidding.
